# Update JSS sheet on specific redux state subtree change

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, vite, jss

I am injecting `JSS` into a manually loaded iframe, and then launching a reload whenever certain values in my `redux` state change, as follows:

```
export default function ETFStyleUpdater({ sheet, id }: Props) {
  const readerConfig = useAppSelector((state) => state.bookReader[id] || DEFAULT_BOOK_READER_CONFIG_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    sheet.update(readerConfig);
  }, [readerConfig]);

  return <></>;
}
```

The `react` code is loaded as follows:

```
  const container = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  createRoot(container!).render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ETFStyleUpdater sheet={sheet} id={bookId} />
    </Provider>,
  );
```

While this felt nasty even when I wrote it, it worked fine *with webpack*. I am now moving to `vitejs`, which complains with a

```
Uncaught Error: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong.
```

This all gets loaded dynamically into an iframe but by accessing the store via a property on `window.parent`, it worked just fine with webpack.

How can I get the same effect without creating a new `react` root and doing a nasty hack with `useEffect`? I tried to put a reference to the `sheet` onto `window` and use a `redux-toolkit` `extraReducer` (or middleware) but it doesn't seem to update, even though there is a reference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redux-watch` seems to do the trick.

```
let w = watch(store.getState, "bookReader");
store.subscribe(
  w((newVal) => {
    sheet.update(newVal[bookId]);
  }),
);
```